# How to define the position of a movieclip in relation to that of another of movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am trying to make a movieclip follow a custom mouse pointer (which is a movieclip) but always stay at a defined postion *(in terms of coordinates)*, a distance away from the mouse pointer on easing to where the mouse pointer is. Below is the code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
Mouse.hide();



var mouseCounter:int = 0;
var mouseDelay:int = 5;// how many frames the mouse must stay still before the follow code is run.    
var speed:Number = 5;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,follow);

// set counter back to zero whenever the mouse is moved. 
function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    wand.x = stage.mouseX;
    wand.y = stage.mouseY;
    e.updateAfterEvent();
    mouseCounter = 0;
}

function follow(e:Event):void
{

    // increment the counter each frame
    mouseCounter++;

    // now run the follow block if the mouse has been still for enough frames. 
    if (mouseCounter >= mouseDelay)
    {
        orb_mc.x -= (orb_mc.x - mouseX) / speed;
        orb_mc.y -= (orb_mc.y - mouseY) / speed;

        orb_mc.x = mouseX + 46.5;
        orb_mc.y = mouseY +50.95;
    }
}
```

The last two lines of codes (26 & 27), is what I used to define the orb_mc's position in relation to the custom mouse pointer which is "wand" however it seems to have resulted in the ease movement of the orb been hampered, so dont know if the positioning code I used is wrong

Comment: Please clarify what do you need. You either want your `orb_mc` to ease in on the position at a given offset from mouse position, or to jump there?

Comment: Yes I want it to ease there instead of jumping there. I was able to achieve the easing before until I defined the position

Comment: I got you @SoloWalker.  one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function follow(e:Event):void
{

    // increment the counter each frame
    mouseCounter++;

    // now run the follow block if the mouse has been still for enough frames. 
    if (mouseCounter >= mouseDelay)
    {
        // Do this:
        orb_mc.x -= (orb_mc.x - mouseX + 46.5) / speed;
        orb_mc.y -= (orb_mc.y - mouseY + 50.95) / speed;

        // OR this:
        //orb_mc.x = orb_mc.x - (orb_mc.x - mouseX + 46.5) / speed;
        //orb_mc.y = orb_mc.y - (orb_mc.y - mouseY + 50.95) / speed;

        // but not both.
    }
}
```

You see, once you use one of the increment assignment operators (`-=`,`+=`,`/=`,`*=`), immediately following that by a regular *assignment* operator will obviously override any value it had before.  You understand that actionscript gets "read" by the computer (this is probably the wrong verbiage but you get my drift) and it reads each block (an area inside a curly brace set `{ }`) from top to bottom.  So the very first time that your `follow` method is called, it is doing 4 things, in order:

1. increment the counter
2. evaluate if `mouseCounter >= mouseDelay`
3. increments `orb_mc` x/y coords
4. **assigns `orb_mc` x/y coords to final destination**

It is doing this on the very first time the `follow` block is read.  This is why both acceptable bits of code in my answer do 2 things:

1. they increment the x/y coords (don't set them to a final value)
2. they change based on a variable factor (`speed`)

Glad it's working!

Comment: Thanks Davis, it works just as I want it. I just replaced the + sign with a - instead so as to get the orb positioned  a distance away from the bottom rather than from the bottom.

Comment: Oh, good to hear!  See my edits for a little more clarity for future reference.